# How to encrypt my hard drive so that it can be opened in Windows, Linux, and Mac OS?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, encryption, macosx

I need to encrypt my external hard drive in such a way that it can be read across OSes. It seems that TrueCrypt was a cross-platform solution, but the software has been declared unsafe to use by its own maintainer.

What's the current option?

Comment: Not sure if this works in all three systems or not: Veracrypt relaced truecrypt not strictly open source
https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/

Comment: LUKS is reported to work on Windows - http://superuser.com/questions/584883/how-can-i-access-volumes-encrypted-with-luks-dm-crypt-from-windows